# Black faces in edit mode and object mode

Tags: faces

This is not a flipped normal issue.  I imported an SVG was working on it to created a shape.  I used 'Bridge edge loops' to create some of my surfaces.  A couple I have had to add manually but a few are jet black.  I cannot see how to change this.  All the other faces are fine.  I'm sure this must be a simple thing I'm doing wrong.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you actually try to flip normals for this face? Not Ctrl+N but Tooslhelf > Shading > Flip Normals. There doesn't appear to be any other reason. If it doesn't work share the file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It could be that the faces are connected to some random vertex in the mesh you forgot to deselect.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have faces with black material applied on this faces:

[image]

Check materials tab and remove black material.

Comment: Thank you it was the material...  Not sure how three faces had black material but sorted now. Thanks for your help,